# In a Calculator, Which Button Should be Bigger: $\sinh()$ or $\rm asin()$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

I am making a calculator app and would like to know: Which of the following functions would be used more often:

- $\sin()$
- $\sinh()$
- $\text{arsin}()$ ($\sin^{-1}$)
- $\text{arsinh}()$ ($\sinh^{-1}$)

Comment: just fyi, the inverse to $\sinh$ is the $\text{arsinh}$, $\text{asinh}$ is incorrect (this notation is used for inverse functions of $\sin$ etc). I thought you ought to know, as you are writing a calculator app ;)

Comment: @CBenni Thanks a ton!

Comment: And it's arcsin, not arsin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sin$ will be used much more often than $\sinh$. As for the inverses, I would expect a calculator to have an `INV` button which changes all trigonometric functions to their inverses.

Comment: Thanks! You just changed how my app works! (Good Thing)

Comment: @ErwaySoftware No problem. Although your design need not mimic hardware calculators, you should still consider what your users may expect of calculators. For example, a popular one in the U.S. is [TI-84](http://2020science.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/TI84plus.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

My experience tells me that $sin^{-1}$ will be pressed the most, then $sin$.

To be honest, I never used the other two buttons in any of high-school problems (and in my basic physics course)

Comment: Thanks! Will take into consideration!